# Ansible register variable from facts output

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm using Ansible playbook to get information about the server's hardware internals through iDrac controller. It is performed by 3rd party module, which uses API to connect to the device.

I get server's internals info (controllers, disks, CPU information, etc.) by running the task. And I would like to register some variables from such output (the output is just shortened by dots).

I kept the main structure of output, to make it clear:

```json
ok: [rac1] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "ca_path": null,
            "idrac_ip": "192.168.168.100",
            "idrac_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "idrac_port": 443,
             ...
        }
    },
    "msg": "Successfully fetched the system inventory details.",
    "system_info": {
        "BIOS": [
            {
                "BIOSReleaseDate": "09/14/2022",
                "FQDD": "BIOS.Setup.1-1",
        …
            }
        ],
        "CPU": [
            {
                "CPUFamily": "Intel(R) Xeon(TM)",
                "Characteristics": "64-bit capable",
                "CurrentClockSpeed": "2.1 GHz",
        …
            },
            {
                "CPUFamily": "Intel(R) Xeon(TM)",
                "Characteristics": "64-bit capable",
        …
            }
        ],
        "Controller": [
            {
                "Bus": "67",
                "CacheSize": "8192.0 MB",
                "DeviceDescription": "RAID Controller in SL 3",
                "FQDD": "RAID.SL.3-1",
                "Key": "RAID.SL.3-1",
        …
            },
```

I need to get only couple values from output (PCI slot num where RAID controller is located):

```yaml
"DeviceDescription": "RAID Controller in SL 3",
"Key": "RAID.SL.3-1"
```

But I have no clue, which example from documentation can I use to register value to variable.

Considering this is a third party module. The task execution is very slow, so it is not so easy for me to play with it as much as possible.

Could somebody suggest me please, which direction should I dig? I'm not a big expert in Ansible yet.

My role's tasks are following below.

I tried to get nested values using debug task(just to figure out key which I need to register), like this, but no luck:

```yaml
### Get inventory key:value pairs and trying to save certain value to variable ###:

- name: Get Inventory
  dellemc.openmanage.idrac_system_info:
    idrac_ip: "{{ idrac_ip }}"
    idrac_user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
    idrac_password: "{{ idrac_password }}"
    validate_certs: False
    register: ansible_facts[system_info][Controller][FQDD].result

### Trying to show my saved variable in this task ###

- name: print registered value
  debug:
    var: RAID slot is at "{{ result }}"
    verbosity: 4
```

I get this message after launching playbook:

> "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (dellemc.openmanage.idrac_system_info) module: register. Supported parameters include: idrac_ip, timeout, idrac_user, ca_path, idrac_port, validate_certs, idrac_password (idrac_pwd)."

Comment: Since you are providing already valid output, how do have generated that? How was it "printed"? "_I need to get only couple values from output _", so you coud just use your `output.system_info.Controller`. "_I need to register_" according the output you have provided it is already registered. "_but not luck_", the last provided task has a syntax error, incorrect indention for keyword `register`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are providing already valid output, how do have generated that? How was it "printed"?

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: rac1
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    result:
      system_info: {
        "BIOS": [
            {
                "BIOSReleaseDate": "09/14/2022",
                "FQDD": "BIOS.Setup.1-1"
            }
        ],
        "CPU": [
            {
                "CPUFamily": "Intel(R) Xeon(TM)",
                "Characteristics": "64-bit capable",
                "CurrentClockSpeed": "2.1 GHz"
            },
            {
                "CPUFamily": "Intel(R) Xeon(TM)",
                "Characteristics": "64-bit capable"
            }
          ],
        "Controller": [
            {
                "Bus": "67",
                "CacheSize": "8192.0 MB",
                "DeviceDescription": "RAID Controller in SL 3",
                "FQDD": "RAID.SL.3-1",
                "Key": "RAID.SL.3-1"
            }
          ]
      }

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.system_info.Controller }}"
```

will result already into the expected output of

```yaml
TASK [Show Facts] *****************************
ok: [rac1] =>
  msg:
  - Bus: '67'
    CacheSize: 8192.0 MB
    DeviceDescription: RAID Controller in SL 3
    FQDD: RAID.SL.3-1
    Key: RAID.SL.3-1
```

Regarding

> *which example from documentation can I use to register value to variable.*

you may read about [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables). For registering results, even for 3rd-party or Custom Modules the structure will be

```yaml
- name: Task
  module_name:
    module_parameter: values
  register: variable_name
```

That's why you get an syntax error

```
Unsupported parameters for (dellemc.openmanage.idrac_system_info) module: register.
```

about the incorrect indention. Therefore try first

```yaml
- name: Get Inventory
  dellemc.openmanage.idrac_system_info:
    idrac_ip: "{{ idrac_ip }}"
    idrac_user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
    idrac_password: "{{ idrac_password }}"
    validate_certs: False
  register: inventory

- name: Show Inventory
  debug:
    msg: "{{ inventory }}"
```

to get familiar with the result set and data structure.

Further documentation which might help are [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) and [`idrac_system_info` module – Get the PowerEdge Server System Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/dellemc/openmanage/idrac_system_info_module.html#return-values).

Comment: Thank you for the hints! At least now I know which direction to move :) I can now experiment to parse this array, by referring to certain array elements.